# Getting an fatal error while loading bitbucket server

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am getting an below attached error when i load my bitbucket server. It was working fine till yesterday. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: Bitbucket error page]

Comment: That message seems fairly self-explanatory. What part are you confused by?

Comment: Currently i have Git 2.26 installed and it was working till yesterday but when i opened bitbucket server its throwing this error. Do i have to downgrade Git version ?@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1):

You need a git version that supports bitbucket atlassian (as described in your error message). On the website from [atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/supported-platforms-776640981.html) is describes which git versions they support.

**Windows**
2.23.0
2.22.0
2.21.0
2.20.1
2.19.2
2.18.1
2.17.2
2.16.5
2.15.3
2.14.5
2.13.7
2.12.5
2.11.4

So you have to downgrade **your version**. Version 2.23 of git can be found here https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/

Download **git-2.23.0.tar.gz** and open it. Then it should work...

Comment: I tried the following steps i am still getting same error with 2.23.0 version as well.

Comment: and now if you write `git --version` it shows **GIT 2.23.0** ?

Comment: It worked with Git 2.20.0 version looks like bitbucket 6 release supports this version.

Comment: Is git **2.20.0** the version you used before updating version to **2.26.0**? And now it works all like before?